# Share an object with in mutiple threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

```
Public ObservableCollection<T> SharedObj=new ObservableCollection<T>(); 

Thread mainThread = new Thread(() => MainThreadMethod(SharedObj);                                                                                      
mainThread.Start();

private DispatcherTimer _graphPlottingTimer=new DispatcherTimer();
_graphPlottingTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_graphPlottingTimer_Tick);
_graphPlottingTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
_graphPlottingTimer.Start();

private void MainThreadMethod(ObservableCollection<T> obj)
{ 
   //here i am adding  rows in obj .
}

void _graphPlottingTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    private List<T> refinedList=new List<T>();

    //I am getting a Collection Modify Exception on the below line
    refinedList =SharedObj.Where(condition).ToList();
}
```

I am getting Collection modify exception on the last line of the **_graphPlottingTimer_Elapsed** method above.

I tried lock and Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke with _graphPlottingTimer_Elapsed
but its still giving same exception.

Answer (score 1):

When you share resources, you need to syncronize access. In your case, your code modified a shared collection while it was being enumerated by the .Where() in your thread.

You need to use a syncronizing object. The simplest way to achieve this in C# is the [lock-Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: lock(thislock){refinedList =SharedObj.Where(condition).ToList();}

Comment: Still its giving collection modify exception

Comment: @AmitSrivastava Update your code please, I'm pretty bad at code review by means of telepathy :)

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you access the ShareObj, you need to lock it. Declare a global object and lock the ShareObj with the same global object each time you access it. Hope this helps!

Comment: lock(thislock){refinedList =SharedObj.Where(condition).ToList();}

Comment: but this not working for me can you please give other solution. thnks

Comment: You are modifying the collection in the MainThreadMethod as well, am I right? You need to lock it in there as well : whenever you access obj, you need to lock it with the same field you lock your list with.
Also, declare SharedObj static for thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following example : [sample from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

You must declare a private variable to lock when you update your list.

Simple sample :

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            ThreadTest tt = new ThreadTest();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                // alter the varialbe shared
                lock (tt.thisLock)
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(() => tt.DoAction(string.Format("Thread-{0}", i)));
                    threads.Add(t);
                    t.Start();
                }
            }
            // wait after each thread
            foreach (Thread item in threads)
            {
                item.Join();
            }
            tt.ReadList();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    internal class ThreadTest
    {
        public Object thisLock = new Object();
        protected IList<string> myList = new List<string>();

        public void DoAction(string info)
        {
            myList.Add(info);
        }

        public void ReadList()
        {
            foreach (string item in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks Matthieu!! i tried this only, private Object thisLock = new Object(); still giving exception

Comment: Collection modify exception

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [Thread-Safe Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)? They allow to modify the collection from different threads as well as deal with potential issues.